# How can I add an end-of-line comment using Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I want to add a comment to the end of a line using Roslyn.

Potentially, I want to add a comment to multiple lines in the same operation, so I would like to work with a **DocumentEditor** or with a **SyntaxRewriter** (CSharpSyntaxRewriter or VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter).

Using a **DocumentEditor** I am able to find the EndOfLineTrivia where I want to insert the comment, but I don't know how to insert the SingleLineCommentTrivia before it.

Is there any way to insert SingleLineCommentTrivia using a DocumentEditor?

Using a **SyntaxRewriter**, I can override the VisitTrivia method and find the EndOfLineTrivia where I want to insert the comment. I can replace the EndOfLineTrivia with SingleLineCommentTrivia, but then the line break is lost.

Is there any way that I can replace EndOfLineTrivia with a sequence of SingleLineCommentTrivia and EndOfLineTrivia using a SyntaxRewriter?

If neither of these methods is possible, what would be a better way to insert an end-of-line comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I have found answers for both cases:

---

Using a **DocumentEditor** you can replace a SyntaxNode, but not a SyntaxTrivia.

However all trivia is associated with a SyntaxNode. What you have to do is to locate that SyntaxNode, create a copy of it with modified trivia and then replace the SytnaxNode.

Using *SyntaxNode.WithTrailingTrivia()*, you can replace the existing trailing trivia with one **or more** SyntaxTrivia objects.

Without going into every detail, the code is roughly:

```
SyntaxNode        OldNode ;
DocumentEditor    RoslynEditor ;

// Initialize OldNode and RoslynEditor ...   

var st      = SyntaxFactory.Comment ( "   // my comment" ) ;
var NewNode = p.WithTrailingTrivia ( st, SyntaxFactory.CarriageReturnLineFeed ) ;

RoslynEditor.ReplaceNode ( p, NewNode ) ;

// and later ...

Dim newRoot = RoslynEditor.GetChangedRoot() ;
```

*Note: This assumes that the end-of-line where the comment should be inserted, is the in the trailing trivia of the SyntaxNode, where it will be replaced. If not, then a new line break will be inserted.*

---

Using a **SyntaxRewriter**, the trick is to use SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine, to generate a SyntaxToken containing both the end-of-line comment and the actual end of line.

Without showing the details of how to select which line to modify, this is the approximate logic:

```
class MLHideRewriterCS : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
  ...

  public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia ( SyntaxTrivia trivia )
  {
    // Some logic to detect the correct line ...
    if ( this is the line that we want to modify )
    {
      var expression = SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine ( "    // my comment" ) ;
      return expression ;
    }

    return base.VisitTrivia ( trivia ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your sharing! Please consider marking [self reply as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)